# returning from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am having problems changing an image in my UI depending on the return value of a boolean variable in my thread.

my class is defined as:

```
class recorderThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
```

I pass in a string, i want a boolean out.
if i cant pass the boolean out then i could do this... but i tried and cant change the image from the thread as follows

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

if (result)
    ball = new Ball(getContext(),R.drawable.correctball);     
else
    ball = new Ball(getContext(),R.drawable.wrongball); 
}
```

Is there not a way I can get the boolean value from calling the thread in the UI?

```
new recorderThread().execute("A");
```

Thanks Guys, hope it makes sense.

Comment: I have two questions to you:
1.Does the AsyncTask is located inside an activity?
2.Is the Ball object holds a reference to the image view that you would like to change or its a decedent of some view like ImageView / ImageButton?

Comment: its not, i dont think. i change the bitmap entirely.

Comment: Ok, i'm sorry... i was confused with the Ball object.
all you have to do is to call
publishProgress(Boolean value) inside doInBackground(...) method and implement onProgressUpdate(Boolean value) which this method allows you to update view's states.

Comment: would this be a faster way to return a boolean value?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why you shouldn't be able to return a boolean from your doInBackground method of the AsyncTask.   Just make sure that the definition is returning a boolean and that you're setting it appropriately for your needs:

```
private class recorderThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
   protected boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
       boolean result;
       // Do your background process and make sure
       // that you set the boolean correctly
       return result;
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(boolean result) {
       // Your current UI stuff here.
   }
}
```

Also, put in lots of logging.  Make sure the boolean is being set correctly.  Also, step through it with the debugger.  Should be an easy fix assuming your correctly updating the UI in your Ball() method.  Note:  check that too to make sure it works correctly.

Comment: Thanks, how do i call this method? i tried:
    hitCorretNote = new recorderThread().execute("A");
but it wants me to add '!=' null on the end...

Comment: Just by calling .execute() on an AsycTask all the methods will be executed.  So, you don't need to assign it to an object.  Just call new recorderThread().execute("A");

Answer (score -1):

Only UI Thread is allowed to modify UI (and your async task runs on separate thread),  so all UI modification shall happpen  via runOnUIThread() of your activity:

```
    activeHighscoreEntry.setTurns(activeHighscoreEntry.getTurns() + 1);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (!handleRemoval(point1)) {
                placeNext();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ok, but see that he implements AsyncTask, which is a custom implementation of Thread, that allows you to change View's properties inside it. Only in - onPreExecute() and - onPostExecute() .

read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html